# Выборка из 1000000 строк в базе

Tags: mysql

Люди добрые подскажите пожалуйста.

Есть таблица с пользователями. В ней 1000000 строк.

Нужно выбрать пользователей у которых в имени не содержится определенной буквы, к примеру.

Как лучше сделать:

1. Выгрузить все 1000000 строк и обработать при помощи RegExp.
2. Делать выборку по определенному количеству записей, к примеру 1000, и проверять через RegExp.

Обязательное условие - Не использовать выборку из базы по определенным параметрам. Например, нельзя использовать `SELECT name FROM users WHERE INSTR(name, 'a') = 0`

Comment: лучше объяснить тому, кто ставил условие, что Земля круглая и все таки пусть база отбирает записи сама.

Comment: @KoVadim это было задание при трудоустройстве.

Comment: если работодатель настаивает, то я бы написал оба варианта и протестировал, что быстрее. Вполне возможно, что от размера выборки все сильно может меняться. Потом показал бы разницу с правильной реализацией. Если все равно будут настаивать на своем - бежать. И бежать с такой компании подальше.

Comment: ваш вопрос касается не базы данных, а того языка на котором это будет делаться. с точки зрения БД выбирать все строки сразу явно лучше, потому что у вас возникнут проблемы с выборкой следующего блока записей например начиная с 1001 отдельным запросом (limit с offset дико тормозит). Но при этом никто не сказал, что 1 млн читаемый одним запросом нельзя обрабатывать блоками или по одной или все сразу в массиве - смотрите каковы возможности вашего языка, сколько доступно памяти

Comment: @Mike Java. Но все равно в любом языке есть нагрузка на саму бд при запросах.

Comment: @KoVadim Мне было дано задание на собеседовании - как бы я сделал. Я ответил что выборка всего и обработка. Но мне ответили что это не правильно.

Comment: И правильно ответили. И даже если бы Вы ответили "выборка по кускам", то ответ все равно был "неправильно".